# parsing an array into a lightbox comment

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, explode

ok guys need your help again,

previously you all introduced me lightbox which after some tweaking has been great. except while using my php code there doesn't seem to be a way to add a caption to the image. now a friend of my introduced me to array using a .txt file. now this is all fine and dandy but i can't seem to get the code that we came up with to read the file correctly. currently it is randomly pulling the letter "a" and the letter "p" and assigning that, which i have no clue where it is getting this.

now here is the code that i've come up with to get the contents of the file.

```
    <?php
    // process caption file into named array

    //open the file
    $myFile = "captions.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r') or die("Can't open file");

    $theData = explode(fread($fh, filesize($myFile)),"\n");


    //close the file
    fclose($fh);


    //parse line by line until there is no data left.
    foreach ($theData as $item => $line) {
     $exploded = explode("=", $line);
     if (count($exploded) == 2) {
     $myFile[$exploded[0]] = $exploded[1];
     }
    }



    ?>
```

and then i'm using the code that auto-populates my image album in turn activating the lighbtox.

```
    <?php

                    $images = glob('*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

                    foreach ($images as $image) {
                        if (file_exists("./thumbs/{$image}")){
                            echo "<a href=\"{$image}\" rel=\"lightbox[gallery]\" title=\"" . $myFile[$image] . "\" style=\"margin-left:25px; margin-right:25px; margin-top:30px; display:inline-block; border:5px solid #fff;\"><img src=\"thumbs/{$image}\" alt=\"{$image}\" /></a>";
                        }
                    }


                    ?>
```

using this code generates no errors but doesn't properly read the captions file.

what i'm wanting to do is have the text file setup with the file name seperated by a = and then the caption.

here is a link to my test page if anyone wants to take a look.

http://outtamymindphoto.myftp.org/images/testalbum/testpage.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by fixing this line:

```
$theData = explode(fread($fh, filesize($myFile)),"\n");
```

According to the PHP Manual , the delimeter is the first parameter.

```
(array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] ))
```

(Read more about `explode` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

The right way:

```
$theData = explode("\n" , fread($fh, filesize($myFile)));
```

You'll also should try to output the variables in order to locate the problem.
For instance , use `var_dump($var)` to check `$var`s value.

Hope I helped you,
comment if you need further help.

Comment: ya, my buddy took another look at the code and realized he made a few errors. he re-wrote it for me and included notes on what he was doing so i can learn from it and compare to the original. the new code is includes everything that you suggested. thank you